# node:internal/errors:496 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, mern

This is what I get on running `npm start`:

Backend server is running!
DB Connection Successfull
hello undefined undefined

```
[
  {
    "_id": new ObjectId("64e5625d681549c42fdfd03e"),
    "title": "Popular Drama Series",
    "type": "new_and_popular",
    "genre": "Drama",
    "content": [
      new ObjectId("64e41ddca4dcec934420c848"),
      new ObjectId("64e41ee9a4dcec934420c849"),
      // ... (truncated for brevity)
    ]
  },
  // ... (more objects)
]
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Coding\RECHECK\Netflix-Clone\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Coding\RECHECK\Netflix-Clone\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Coding\RECHECK\Netflix-Clone\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at C:\Coding\RECHECK\Netflix-Clone\api\routes\lists.js:62:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) 
{
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

and this is the `lists.js` file mentioned in the error:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const List = require("../models/List");
const verify = require("../verifyToken");

// CREATE

router.post("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    const newList = new List(req.body);
    try {
      const savedList = await newList.save();
      return res.status(201).json(savedList);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

// DELETE

router.delete("/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    try {
      await List.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      return res.status(201).json("The list has been delete...");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

// GET

router.get("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const typeQuery = req.query.type;
  const genreQuery = req.query.genre;
  console.log("hello", typeQuery, genreQuery);
  let list = [];
  try {
    if (typeQuery) {
      if (genreQuery) {
        list = await List.aggregate([
          { $sample: { size: 10 } },
          { $match: { type: typeQuery, genre: genreQuery } },
        ]);
      } else {
        list = await List.aggregate([
          { $sample: { size: 10 } },
          { $match: { type: typeQuery } },
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      list = await List.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }]);
    }
    console.log(list);
    return res.status(200).json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I find it surprising as i was not having this error the last time i ran my project, it was running completely fine the last time i ran it.

It has been two months since i have gone back to check to run the project and the only two changes that i had done were install the new node version and resume mongodb atlas cluster as it was inactive.

I have tried downgrading to a previous node version and ran it to check if it solves anything but no success, previously the lists.js file didnt have return statements where the res.json commands are shown, I saw online that adding return statements to res.status.json would solve it i have tried adding them to all my route files including this one lists.js still nothing.

I have even tried reinstalling npm modules to no avail. I have tried searching through other posts in stack overflow and almost everyone gives the same answer to use return. Before running it today i had first uploaded it to github so after running it and seeing that it wasnt working i cloned the older version to test it but it still gave the same error.

I'm dont know too much indepth of node.js so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Just so everyone knows this lists.js and another movies.js are the only two files giving this problem if I comment the line giving the error on lists.js for the last catch block, the error then shows for the catch block of movies.js if i comment this line, it shows error on lists.js but for the try block connected to that catch block if i comment that line, it shows error for the movies.js try block connected to that catch block and finally if i comment this line, no error shows but i am not able to get data from backend as the `return res.status(200).json(list);` was the line i had to comment

this is the movies.js file:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Movie = require("../models/Movie");
const verify = require("../verifyToken");

//CREATE
router.post("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    const newMovie = new Movie(req.body);
    try {
      const savedMovie = await newMovie.save();
      return res.status(201).json(savedMovie);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

//UPDATE

router.put("/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    try {
      const updatedMovie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
          $set: req.body,
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      return res.status(200).json(updatedMovie);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

//DELETE
router.delete("/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    try {
      await Movie.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      return res.status(200).json("The movie has been deleted...");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

//GET

router.get("/find/:id", verify, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id);
    return res.status(200).json(movie);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET RANDOM

router.get("/random", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const type = req.query.type;
  let movie;
  try {
    if (type === "series") {
      movie = await Movie.aggregate([
        { $match: { isSeries: true } },
        { $sample: { size: 9 } },
      ]);
    } else {
      movie = await Movie.aggregate([
        { $match: { isSeries: false } },
        { $sample: { size: 9 } },
      ]);
    }
    return res.status(200).json(movie);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET ALL

router.get("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    try {
      const movies = await Movie.find();
      return res.status(200).json(movies.reverse());
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You are not allowed!");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

error occurs here for the get method for this route `/find/:id`

EDIT:
Ok new update on checking my verify middleware thanks to @Phil, i checked that i was using JWT within the code and it was not having a return so i added it and it gave no error but strangely no data was being retrieved from the db so i thought ill check abt the current state of JWT online and found out that by 8th of Sept 2023 JWT has been deprecated for node, so now i have to migrate to OAuth or server-to-server apps.

Comment: you are getting error at  line number 62 in lists.js file(ists.js:62:28). This error is occuring because your application is sending two response at a time from one api call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: I'd be looking at your `verify` middleware. As far as I can see, that's the only place that could be sealing the response

Comment: @ashwanibakshi i have tried commenting that line and running the code, if you see the lists.js its the last catch statement on that file, the one just before module.exports = router; but if i do that the next error shows for the last try block which is connected to this last catch statement, the error shows for this return res.status(200).json(list); but if i comment this as well i wont be able to retreive my data from backend but the program shows no error and it shows i have retreived content from the db in the cconsole

Comment: @Phil Im not an advanced user of node just wanted youll to know that so I may not be able to know everything but on reading through all what people have written on that post and most related posts i got that we should use return before the response statement but as you can see it still doesnt work, if there was a direct answer to try out like that result i would give that a shot, thx btw

Comment: @Phil i will check out that verify middleware thx for the feedback

Comment: Thx a lot @Phil i have written my findings in the latest edit of my post